# Dualboot Ubuntu 20.04 with Windows 10 on SSD and data on HDD

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd, 20.04

I want to dualboot Ubuntu 20.04LTS with windows 10, but have ubuntu system files and home on SSD, while keeping pictures, downloads and other data on ssd.                                                  I had a linux installation but i had to remove it because i was encountering really slow bootup.

The configuration of my laptop is as follows: 8GB RAM, 1 TB HDD+256GB SSD, Nvidia GTX 1050.

I have cleaned my SSD (with windows install) as much as I could and I have 141GB free. I have disabled fast startup and secure boot. It was suggested in tutorials. But I've read Ubuntu Supports Secure boot.

Please review my plan of action and identify possible errors. I am new to this but this is what i have accumulated by reading articles so far.

This is what I plan to do:
        .
 1. Make unallocated partition on 70GB on my SSD NVme M.2 PCI.
 2. Make another partition on my hdd of 350 GB.           .
 3. Install ubuntu again and during installation select the SSD partition for allocating root(35GB) and swap for (12GB) and home(23GB).
 4. After installation configure ubuntu to mount HDD automatically on every startup.
 5. Configure the HDD partition to store downloads, movies and pictures, keep it NTFS so I can also access it using windows too.

Q1: I have confusion regarding my fifth step. How to configure settings after installation to have all of data in the HDD partition, I've read about symlinks. Is it the way to go?

Q2: I have cleaned my SSD (with windows install) as much as I could and I have 141GB free, I plan to keep approxx 70GB for windows. Is it the correct size?

Q3: Do I need to have swap for hibernation if I am going to have really fast bootup speeds?
                                                                                                          Q4 : The reason I am making the home partition on windows is because I read somewhere that home contains system settings and stuff. I also plan to install Cuda Drivers and Tensorflow-gpu later which would make it faster to have on SSD I guess. If mounting home on HDD will not make a difference , then I can continue to so(I won't have to create symlinks later then).  So I need help regarding this too.

Q5 : My issue is slightly similar to   ![How to partition for Windows/Ubuntu dual boot on same SSD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/643091/how-to-partition-for-windows-ubuntu-dual-boot-on-same-ssd). Should I follow the partition given in this link?

Thank you so  much for your time and help. :)

Comment: @user535733 I had ubuntu for a month on my HDD to use Nvidia Cuda with cuBlas and nvBLAS for Octave and tensorflow-gpu(Since it wasnt working in Win10). But I had made only 100GB of total storage and realised that it wasnt going to work well with the slow hdd. That is why I am looking forward for making this change.

Comment: I have a computer with both Windows and Ubuntu installed mainly on a SSD. I set Windows target location for the Desktop, Documents, Downloads, etc folders to the HDD and also installed Ubuntu /home partition to the HDD. (because the SSD is only 128GB). When I got a new drive for my laptop I bought a 1TB SSD. I don't think hibernation helps startup speed much, just every program that was open stays open.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron thank you for the reply, how much space did you allocate for root? and did you make a swap partition on ssd?

Comment: I think root is about 25GB. Swap started out on the SSD but got moved to the HDD as I rarely hibernate nowadays.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron thanks a lot. replying from ubuntu on ssd. systemd-analyze it at 19s tho, but every service is literally in ms so i dont know how to identify what is slow

Comment: I keep /home inside / and use 25 or 30GB for /. My current 20.04 is using 8.4GB, but both 16.04 & 18.04 grew to about 12GB. But I do not game and have all data including Thunderbird & Firefox in data partition(s). I just got new larger NVMe drive & moved data from HDD to SSD and HDD is now mostly backup or test installs. I now use swap file default, no swap partition. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk

Comment: @oldfred thank you !!